# How to sort a list of entities on the property from a collection of entities

Tags: java, sorting, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity `Mission` which has a collection of entities `Trip`, and I would like to be able to sort the mission in function of the content in the collection of `Trip`.

The `Trip` entity:

```
@Entity
public Class Trip {
    @Id private Long id;
    @Column private LocalDateTime time;
}
```

The `Mission` entity:

```
@Entity
public Class Mission {
    @Id private Long id;
    @Column private String city;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "mission")
    private Collection<Trip> trips;
}
```

The `Mission` Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface MissionRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Mission, Long>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Mission>, QuerydslBinderCustomizer<QMission> {

    @Override
    default void customize(final QuerydslBindings bindings, final QMission mission) {
        bindings.bind(String.class).first((final StringPath path, final String value) -> path.containsIgnoreCase(value));
        bindings.including(mission.city);
        bindings.excludeUnlistedProperties(true);
    }

    Page<T> findAll(Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable);
}
```

The `Mission` Service:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class MissionService {

    private final MissionRepository missionRepository;

    @Autowired
    public MissionService(final MissionRepository missionRepository) {
        this.missionRepository = missionRepository;
    }

    public Page<Mission> findAll(final Predicate predicate, final Pageable pageable) {
        return this.missionRepository.findAll(predicate, pageable);
    }
}
```

The `Mission` Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/missions")
public class MissionController {

    private final MissionService missionService;

    @Autowired
    public MissionController(final MissionService missionService) {
        this.missionService = missionService;
    }

    @GetMapping
    @ResponseBody
    public Page<Mission> getAllMissions(@QuerydslPredicate(root = Mission.class) final Predicate predicate, @PageableDefault final Pageable pageable) {
        return this.missionService.findAll(predicate, pageable);
    }
}
```

When calling `/api/missions?sort=city,DESC`, it work perfectly.
But when calling `/api/missions?sort=trips.time,DESC` I am getting duplicate entries which match the number of Trips linked with a Mission.
All these mission are correctly sorted, but the duplicate part is just a no go…

The objective is to be able to sort the `Mission` (`ASC` or `DESC`) in function of the departure date from the `Trip` collection (which would be the first `Trip` sorted in `ASC`).

So, how to sort this list of `Mission` on the content from the collection of `Trip` without getting the duplication part?

I would also like to avoid changing the REST method signature or the database structure, if possible.

I was thinking of adding a `DISTINCT` on the list, but It wouldn't work as the sorting need to be on the first Trip's time field. Sorting in `ASC` mode would work. But in `DESC`, it would then be sorted in function of the arrival date, and not the departure…

A crazy idea: would it be possible to automatically fill a transient property in the mission with the content of a query, and sort on it using the `Pageable` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 1 – First option

I was able to fix my problem by using the `@Formula` annotation from Hibernate.

### 1.1 – Adding the following property inside the `Mission` entity

```
@Formula("(select min(t.time) from Trip t where t.mission_id = id)")
private LocalDateTime startDate;
```

### 1.2 – Sorting on the property

We just need to call the property.

`/api/missions?sort=startDate,DESC`.

---

## 2 – Second option

Currently I don't have any performance issue.
Yet, just in case, I am also considering to use a view which will then be linked to my entity.

**NB: This one wasn't test, but is based on my understanding from the following [blog](https://blog.eyallupu.com/2009/07/hibernate-derived-properties.html).**

### 2.1 – Create the view based on tables `Trip` and `Mission`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW mission_derived AS
select 
  m.`id` as id,
  min(t.`time`) as startDate
from `trip` t
inner join `mission` m on t.`mission_id` = m.`id`
group by m.`id`;
```

### 2.2 – Create the java entity matching this view

```
@Entity
@Immutable
public class MissionDerived {

  @Id
  private long id;

  @Column
  private Date startDate;

}
```

### 2.3 – Adding the property to my `Mission` entity

```
@OneToOne
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="ID")
private MissionDerived derived;
```

### 2.4 – Sorting using this property

We would then need to call the property from the mission, and then the property from the derived entity.

`/api/missions?sort=derived.startDate,DESC`